# Seeking help with theorem proof (Propositional Logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

During the beginning of my Logic class, my professor wrote a theorem on the board as an example, saying that it would be something we could easily prove after a few weeks in the course. I wrote it down and have tried solving it, but no luck. Last week, I asked him about it, and he said that yes, we have learned enough rules to sufficiently prove the theorem. Only problem is, I'm struggling.

At this point, it doesn't really matter (not for a grade or anything) but it's bugging me that I can't figure it out, and the professor has kind of turned this into a game/challenge for me to figure it out (I think he enjoys seeing me struggle since I'm usually one of the better performing students).

The theorem is as follows:

: (A → B) ∨ (B → C)

The thing is, I can clearly see why it's true in my mind, but I can't figure out a way to use the given rules to solve it. As of right now, the only tools we've learned are conjunction I/E, disjunction I/E, Biconditional I/E, Conditional Proofs/Assumptions, MP, MT, Double Negation I/E, and RAA. (I/E is for introduction/elimination). I've read ways to do it using truth tables, but that's not available to us at the moment.

Any help on this, anything from a starting point hint to a full proof, would be much appreciated!

Edit: According to the professor, the proof he's expecting should be within 20-25 lines, and we're not using logical equivalences or truth tables.

Comment: You need: $B \lor \lnot B$ and then apply $\lor$-elim to it.

Comment: Are you saying I should start with B∨¬B as an assumption? If so, I'm not sure where to go with that. If not, I'm not sure how to get to B∨¬B from any starting point.

Comment: The issue is (also regarding the answer below) : have you to use Natural Deduction or other "tools" (like logical equivalences ot truth table) are allowed ?

Comment: No, logical equivalences and truth tables aren't allowed. The theorem is supposedly solvable with what we've learned so far, which is only what I outlined in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4), we need *LEM* or the equivalent *DN*, because the formula is not intuitionistically valid.

1) $B$ --- assumed [a]

2) $B \lor \lnot B$ --- by $\lor$-intro

3) $\lnot (B \lor \lnot B)$ --- assumed [b]

4) $\bot$ --- contradiction: 2) and 3)

5) $\lnot B$ --- by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [a]

6) $B \lor \lnot B$ --- by $\lor$-intro

7) $\bot$ --- contradiction: 3) and 6)

8) $B \lor \lnot B$ --- by *DN*, discharging [b].

Up to now, we have proved (classically) : $\vdash B \lor \lnot B$ (no open assumptions left).

Now we will start from 8) :

9) $B$ --- assumed [$c_1$] from 8) for $\lor$-elim

10) $A \to B$ --- from 9) by $\to$-intro

> 11) $(A \to B) \lor (B \to C)$ --- by $\lor$-intro.

12) $\lnot B$ --- assumed [$c_2$] from 8) for $\lor$-elim

13) $B$ --- assumed [d]

14) $\bot$ --- contradiction

15) $C$ --- from 14) by $\bot$-elim

16) $B \to C$ --- by $\to$-intro, discharging [d]

> 17) $(A \to B) \lor (B \to C)$ --- by $\lor$-intro.

Having derived $(A \to B) \lor (B \to C)$ from assumptions $B$ and $\lnot B$, we may apply $\lor$-elim:

> > $(A \to B) \lor (B \to C)$ --- from 9)-11) and 12)-17) and 8) by $\lor$-elim, discharging [$c_1$] and [$c_2$].

Comment: I understand most of this, however we haven't learned ⊥-elim, so I'm unsure how you got to 15) from 13)-14).

Comment: @JarmenK.: All natural deduction systems surely can make use of a contradiction (two contradictory sentences), which you do have from (12) and (13). If you don't have explosion (which Mauro used), but have double negation elimination, you can still get (15) by introducing a subcontext where $\neg C$ and pulling in the contradiction.

Comment: So you would assume ~C and then use RAA to get the negation, and use DNE to get C?

Answer (score 1):

$X \rightarrow Y$ is false if and only if $X$ is true and $Y$ is false. Thus, if $B$ is true, then $A \rightarrow B$ is true and your statement is true. On the other hand, if $B$ is false, then $B \rightarrow C$ is true and your statement is true. So the theorem is true.

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Truth_table

---

In logical language.

\begin{align}(A \rightarrow B) \lor (B \rightarrow C) 
&\Longleftrightarrow ( \lnot A \lor B) \lor (\lnot B \lor C) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \lnot A \lor (B \lor \lnot B) \lor C \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \lnot A \lor \text{True} \lor C \\
&\Longleftrightarrow\text{True} \\
\end{align}

Comment: The problem isn't one of whether it's true or not; I was assured that the theorem is true. The exercise is to write out a valid proof to prove it. Also, as said above, truth tables aren't being used.

Comment: @JarmenK. Yes, and proving is nothing else than showing that it's true for all possible truth values of $A,B,C$. My argumentation shows that it's true for $B$ true and also for $B$ false, no matter what $A$ and $C$ are. Thus, the theorem is true for any $A,B,C$ and is proven.

Comment: You're right, so I apologize for the misunderstanding. When I say "I have to prove it," I mean I have to have it written out in the logical language that we're using, with proper notation etc., not just verbal reasoning.

Comment: @JarmenK. I added some stuff to my answer, I hope that's what you wanted. It uses an alternative expression for $\rightarrow$ from that wiki page and the associative law of $\lor$.

Comment: That does help a little, however the associative law is not one we've covered yet, so it's off-limits for this proof. As I outlined in the original question, I need to use what we've learned so far, which includes disjunction elimination and reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: @JarmenK. And why is simply evaluating the expression for $B$ true and $B$ false off-limits? That's the most basic thing imaginable. It's hard to do anything if even stuff like $B \lor \lnot B$ true is forbidden. If you need a super fancy proof for such a simple thing then I have to opt out.

Comment: Apologies again, it's nearly 5am so I'm not at 100%. We haven't used the term "associative law" and I assumed it was something we hadn't covered. Though using "true" and "false" as part of the formulas aren't something we've done yet, so I'd assume it's not part of the expected proof, which is estimated to be around 20-25 lines (from the professor).